# Sass doesn't load the .scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, sinatra

I am new to programming and I am trying to make a simple website as an exercise. I use :

- ruby
- sinatra
- sass
- base(bitters)
- bourbon
- neat

The problem I'm facing has something to do with sass, it doesn't load my "style.scss":

**application.rb:**

```
require "sinatra"

get "/" do
   erb :Home
end

get "/style.css" do 
   scss :"scss/style"
end
```

**layout.erb:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/style.css" >
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>




    <div class="article">

        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Home.erb:**

```
<p> text </p>
```

**style.scss:**

```
@import "normalize";
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "base/base";
@import "neat/neat";

$column: 90px;
$gutter: 30px;
$grid-columns: 10;
$max-width: em(720);

body {
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
}

a {
    color: #CC1212;
}

div.article {
    @include outer-container;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
```

The error message says: *Sass::SyntaxError - File to import not found or unreadable: neat-helpers*

All the .scss files from Bourbon, neat and base have an underscore before the actual name.

So neat.scss => _neat.scss

I don't get what's wrong. Could you help me and maybe explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a compiler that's going to  convert the file to CSS. Use the compass gem to do that.

Here's a basic implementation you can follow:

https://github.com/Compass/compass/wiki/Sinatra-Integration